# How can I disable jar compression in sbt using sbtassembly?

Tags: sbt

I'm interested in building uncompressed jar files to make my rsync faster when only a few classes change and so far, i can't figure out how to tell [sbtassembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to disable compression.

```
server > inspect assembly
[info] Task: java.io.File
[info] Description:
[info]  Builds a single-file deployable jar.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/.../}server/*:assembly
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  server/*:assembly-merge-strategy(for assembly)
[info]  server/*:assembly-output-path(for assembly)
[info]  server/*:package-options(for assembly)
[info]  server/*:assembly-assembled-mappings(for assembly)
[info]  server/*:cache-directory
[info]  server/*:test(for assembly)
[info]  server/*:streams(for assembly)
[info] Delegates:
[info]  server/*:assembly
[info]  {.}/*:assembly
[info]  */*:assembly
```

...

```
server > inspect assembly-option(for assembly)
[info] Setting: sbtassembly.AssemblyOption = AssemblyOption(true,true,true,<function1>)
[info] Description:
[info]  
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/.../}server/*:assembly-option(for assembly)
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  server/*:assembly-assemble-artifact(for package-bin)
[info]  server/*:assembly-assemble-artifact(for assembly-package-scala)
[info]  server/*:assembly-assemble-artifact(for assembly-package-dependency)
[info]  server/*:assembly-excluded-files(for assembly)
...
```

[AssemblyOption](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/src/main/scala/sbtassembly/Plugin.scala#L396) doesn't say anything about packaging, however, and the plugin seems to use sbt's own [Package](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.12.1/main/actions/Package.scala) for that, so maybe there's a way to configure *that*? Package, in turn, calls [IO.jar(...)](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.12.1/util/io/IO.scala#L364) to write the file. That uses [withZipOutput](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.12.1/util/io/IO.scala#L461) to make a ZipOutputStream (or a JarOutputStream), on which i'd want to call [setMethod(ZipOutputStream.STORED)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#setMethod%28int%29), but i can't.

Any ideas other than an sbt feature request?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this directly via sbt configuration, since sbt assumes that any files within zip and jar artifacts should be compressed.

One workaround is to unzip and re-zip (without compression) the jar file.  You can do this by adding the following setting to your project (e.g. in *build.sbt*):

```
packageBin in Compile <<= packageBin in Compile map { file =>
  println("(Re)packaging with zero compression...")
  import java.io.{FileInputStream,FileOutputStream,ByteArrayOutputStream}
  import java.util.zip.{CRC32,ZipEntry,ZipInputStream,ZipOutputStream}
  val zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))
  val tmp = new File(file.getAbsolutePath + "_decompressed")
  val zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tmp))
  zos.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.STORED)
  Iterator.continually(zis.getNextEntry).
    takeWhile(ze => ze != null).
    foreach { ze =>
      val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
      Iterator.continually(zis.read()).
        takeWhile(-1 !=).
        foreach(baos.write)
      val bytes = baos.toByteArray
      ze.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED)
      ze.setSize(baos.size)
      ze.setCompressedSize(baos.size)
      val crc = new CRC32
      crc.update(bytes)
      ze.setCrc(crc.getValue)
      zos.putNextEntry(ze)
      zos.write(bytes)
      zos.closeEntry
      zis.closeEntry
    } 
  zos.close
  zis.close
  tmp.renameTo(file)
  file
}
```

Now when you run `package` in sbt, the final jar file will be uncompressed, which you can verify with `unzip -vl path/to/package.jar`.